# How to send text with selenium python to a iframe within a <!DOCTYPE html>?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to select a text box which is in the form of a `<!DOCTYPE html>`

[image]

Here's the HTML:

[image]

I tried pretty much everything and either I end up with nothing.
Here's my code

```
desc =WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tinymce"]')))
desc.clear()
desc.send_keys("anynaynanya")
```

If I used the xpath of the iframe I get that error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dln\Desktop\tstsd.py", line 22, in <module>
    desc.clear()
  File "C:\Users\Dln\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 95, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Dln\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dln\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Dln\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

Comment: Amr, please update the question with error encountered.

Comment: Most of RTE is an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<p>` element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#textarea-WYSIWYG_ifr")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.mce-content-body#tinymce > p"))).send_keys("anynaynanya")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='textarea-WYSIWYG_ifr']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body[@id='tinymce' and @class='mce-content-body']/p"))).send_keys("anynaynanya")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 2):

## Try switching to frame first

To switch to the frame with frame name

```
driver.switch_to.frame("framename")
```

check out this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-frames-in-selenium-with-python

Answer (score 1):

To access any frame you first need to switch to it. Just to make sure that there is frame on frame on webpage, you may find the frames by tag name `iframe`

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

A list of frames available will be given. This is just to be more sure about the presence of frame.
To send some text inside you need to switch to frame, that you can do by providing the index well as frame name.

```
driver.switch_to.frame()
```

Note: Index no. starts from 0